# Increasing sequence of events and the probability of their limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If $A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset\cdots$ is an increasing sequence of events with limit $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(A_n)=P(A)$$

My attempt so far:

Since $A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset\cdots$ is increasing and $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n \wedge A=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n=A$. I have that $$P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n\right)=P(A)\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n)=P(A)$$

Answer (score 7):

Let $B_1 = A_1$ and $B_{n+1} = A_{n+1}\setminus A_n$ for $n\ge 1$.  Then
$$
A_N = \bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n
$$
and
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n,
$$
and
$$
B_n \cap B_m = \varnothing \text{ for } n\ne m.
$$
So
\begin{align}
P(A) & = P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) = P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n \right) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(B_n) \qquad \left( \begin{array}{l} \text{by countable additivity of } P \text{ and} \\ \text{pairwise disjointness of } \{B_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \end{array} \right) \\[10pt]
& = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N P(B_n) = \lim_{N\to\infty} P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n \right) = \lim_{N\to\infty} P(A_N).
\end{align}

Comment: Is this a canonical proof of continuity of probabilities? I saw it in Rosenthal's 'A First Look at Rigorous Probability'

Answer (score 0):

Hint: One usually requires from a probability to be $\sigma$-additive, i.e. when $(B_i)_{i\geq 1}$ is a countable disjointed family, then $P(\bigcup_i B_i)=\sum_i P(B_i)$. So try to rewrite your increasing union as a countable union of disjoint sets.