# Alternate approach on probability proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

Let $A_1,A_2,...$ be an infinite sequence of events which is monotonically increasing, $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for every $n$. Let $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Show that $P(A)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$.

My approach : As the $A_i$'s are monotonically increasing, their respective probabilities are monotonically increasing as well. (Not sure if this holds, but my argument is each subsequent $A_i$ is a larger set, contains more or equal elements => greater probability) Therefore, $P(A_1) \leq \cdot \cdot \cdot \leq P(A_n) \leq \cdot \cdot$.

Claim : The sequence $P(A_i)$ is bounded above by $P(A)$.

Suppose P(A) is not the upper bound of the sequence $P(A_i)$, then at least $\exists n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $P(A_{n_1}) \geq P(A)$. But since $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$, if there exists an event $A_{n_1}$, where $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(A_{n_1}) \geq P(A)$ then $A \leq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Contradiction.

Therefore, since the sequence $P(A_i), i \in \mathbb{N}$ is bounded above by $P(A)$, it converges to $P(A)$, which implies $P(A)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just curious whether this works or not.

I know someone else has posted this question already, link :[Increasing sequence of events and the probability of their limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956702/increasing-sequence-of-events-and-the-probability-of-their-limit).

Comment: I would slightly modify your proof: $P(A) \ge P(A_n)$ because $P(A) = P(A\setminus A_n) + P(A_n)$ and probability is non-negative. (We split the bigger set $A$ into its subset $A_n$ and everything else). 

Unfortunately the latter implication is false – $P(A_n)$ is bounded above by $2$, for example, but it does not converge to it. The question you are referring to has an excellent answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1956726/551592

Comment: May I ask how is the implication false ?

Comment: Implication: "if $a_n$ is bounded above by $b$, then $\lim a_n = b$" is false. Example: the constant sequence $a_n = 1/2$ is bounded above by, say, $42$.

Comment: You only proved that $P(A)$ is an upperbound but needed is to prove that $P(A)$ is the *least* upperbound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not prove yet that the sequence "converges" to $P(A)$.

(It does not exclude that it converges to some value less than $P(A)$.)

For a real proof you should have a look at the sets $B_n=A_n-\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k$.

They are disjoint and satisfy:$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=A$$
Then consequently: $$P(A)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(B_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(B_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)$$