# For a birth and death process, prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(X_n=0) $ exists.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, birth-death-process

I found this question in a book, and I do not know how to prove it. The author claims the following:

Consider a populations capable of generating children. Let $X_n$ be the number of individuals in generation $n$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n =0)$ exists.

How would one prove such existence?

Comment: Need further information such as distribution function for child production.

Comment: What about the deaths?

Comment: Do all parents from generation $n-1$ die and only their children make up generation $n$?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process it might answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, none of this information is given. What I’ve written is all there is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, then,

$$(X_{n} =0) \subset (X_{n+1} = 0)$$

Indeed if you have no individuals at generation $n$ then you have no individuals at generation $n+1$.

Therefore, using the properties of increasing sequence of events we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n=0)$ exists and moreover,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n=0)=P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} \ (X_n=0) \right)$$

Comment: Proof of this result can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956702/increasing-sequence-of-events-and-the-probability-of-their-limit